# onActivityResult() is not being called, but works elsewhere

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a activity that calls another waiting a result (`startActivityForResult()`). This second activity is just an explanation to the user and independent of what they do, I want to open a native screen to make the user allow the permissions that are missing. I can open this second activity normally, however the `onActivityResult()` never is called.

In the same project there is another pair of activities that do the same and they work fine. These 2 are equal in code terms but they do not work anyway.

**First Activity**

```
public class RingtonesActivity extends Activity {


    private boolean falta2Per = false;
    private boolean faltaSoPerEsc = false;
    private boolean faltaSoPerConf = false;

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION_RING = 0x0009;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_WRITE_PERMISSION = 0x001;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                …
    }


    private View.OnClickListener onClickToque() {
        return new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                new MudarToquesTask().execute();
                finish();
            }
        };
    }



    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION_RING) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(RingtonesActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(RingtonesActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS)
                            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                LogUtil.i("RINGTONES - Pedindo as 2 permissões.");
                falta2Per = true;
                //ped as 2 perm
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                                Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS},
                        REQUEST_CODE_WRITE_PERMISSION);
            } else {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(RingtonesActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    faltaSoPerEsc = true;
                    LogUtil.i("RINGTONES - Pedindo permissão de esc.");
                    //ped a perm de esc em area ext
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                            REQUEST_CODE_WRITE_PERMISSION);
                }

                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(RingtonesActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    faltaSoPerConf = true;
                    LogUtil.i("RINGTONES - Pedindo permissão p/ alt as conf");
                    //ped a perm p/ alt as conf
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS},
                            REQUEST_CODE_WRITE_PERMISSION);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_WRITE_PERMISSION:
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                    if (falta2Per) {
                        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                                grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            LogUtil.i("RINGTONES - Ambas as per concedidas.");
                            showDefaultToast(R.drawable.blink_emot, getString(R.string.agora_funciona));
                        } else {
                            if (grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                LogUtil.i("RINGTONES - Per de esc negada.");
                                showDefaultToast(R.drawable.lagrima_emot, "Desculpe, mas você negou a permissão de escrita.\nO app não podera realizar essa tarefa.");
                            }

                            if (grantResults[1] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                LogUtil.i("RINGTONES - Per p/ alt conf negada.");
                                showDefaultToast(R.drawable.lagrima_emot, "Desculpe, mas você negou a permissão para alterar as configurações.\nO app não podera realizar essa tarefa.");
                            }
                        }

                        falta2Per = false;
                    }

                    if (faltaSoPerEsc) {
                        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            LogUtil.i("RINGTONES - Perm de esc concedida.");
                            showDefaultToast(R.drawable.blink_emot, getString(R.string.agora_funciona));
                        } else {
                            LogUtil.i("RINGTONES - Per de esc negada.");
                            showDefaultToast(R.drawable.lagrima_emot, "Desculpe, mas você negou a permissão de escrita.\nO app não podera realizar essa tarefa.");
                        }

                        faltaSoPerEsc = false;
                    }

                    if (faltaSoPerConf) {
                        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            LogUtil.i("RINGTONES - Perm p/ alt as conf concedida.");
                            showDefaultToast(R.drawable.blink_emot, getString(R.string.agora_funciona));
                        } else {
                            LogUtil.i("RINGTONES - Per p/ alt as conf negada.");
                            showDefaultToast(R.drawable.lagrima_emot, "Desculpe, mas você negou a permissão para alterar as configurações.\nO app não podera realizar essa tarefa.");
                        }

                        faltaSoPerConf = false;
                    }

                } else {
                    LogUtil.i("RINGTONES - Ambas as per negadas");
                    showDefaultToast(R.drawable.lagrima_emot, "Desculpe, mas você negou a(s) permissões. O app não podera realizar essa tarefa.");
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Task p/ altera o toque ou o som do sms numa thread aparte
     */
    private class MudarToquesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(RingtonesActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) ==
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(RingtonesActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                   ...

                } else {
                    LogUtil.i("RINGTONES - Falta ao menos uma das 2 permissões. Exibindo tela de explicações.");
                    hasPermission = false;
                    startActivityForResult(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PermissionExplainRingtonesActivity.class),
                            REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION_RING);
                }


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            ...

            }
        }

    }
}
```

---

**Second Activity**

```
public class PermissionExplainRingtonesActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_permission_explain_ringtones);
    inits();
}

private void inits() {
    Button btnEntendi = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_entendi);
    btnEntendi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setResult(RESULT_OK);
            finish();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    setResult(RESULT_OK);
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

}

Comment: Why do you call `startActivityForResult` from `doInBackground `? As I remember, Activity manipulations should happen in main thread so for main thread it should be called from `onPostExecute`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `AsyncTask` is calling `startActivityForResult` in the background. Try changing your code and calling it in the UI thread, maybe in `onPostExecute` of your `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Really thx, all of you are right. It's strange 'cause I had try call startActivityForResult() in other threads a few times (before use it in this app) and worked normally... The other pair of activity also used other thread, and worked. But this one don't. Anyway, I changed all activities of project to be called just in UI Thread. Now all of them works. THX.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're calling `startActivityForResult` from another thread which is why it breaks, like other people have mentioned. But you dont even need to use an `AsyncTask` because all you want to do is check for permission and start an activity if the app already doesn't have the permissions.

This isn't a long or UI blocking task so it can be done on the main thread itself.

Answer (score 1):

AsyncTask should be used if you are executing some heavy operations, and do not want to block the main UI Thread. In ur case, for checking the permissions granted, you do not require to execute this on the background thread, can be done on the main thread.

The reason for `onActivityResult ()` not getting called because startActivityForResult is being called from a different thread(background thread)

[Official Doc](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)